# ValueError: cannot select an axis to squeeze out which has size not equal to one

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape out_hmaps=(2, 6, 64, 64, 1)

i want it to be  (6, 64, 64, 1).
I tried `np.squeeze(np.array(out_hmaps),0)` it worked once ,but then throws the following error.

```
 File "train.py", line 56, in <module>
xnet.train(epochs=args.epochs, model_path=args.model_path, batch_size=args.batch_size)
File "C:/Users/srira/Desktop/hourglass_keras-master/src/net\hourglass.py", line 54, in train
self.model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_dataset.get_dataset_size() // batch_size,
File "D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1918, in fit_generator
return self.fit(
File "D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1108, in fit
data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(
File "D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1348, in 
get_data_handler
return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1138, in __init__
self._adapter = adapter_cls(
File "D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 793, in __init__
peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
File "D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 850, in _peek_and_restore
peek = next(x)
File "C:/Users/srira/Desktop/hourglass_keras-master/src/data_gen\mpii_datagen.py", line 88, in generator
yield np.array(train_input), np.squeeze(np.array(out_hmaps),0)
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in squeeze
File "D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1508, in squeeze
return squeeze(axis=axis)
ValueError: cannot select an axis to squeeze out which has size not equal to one
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: well where do you want you additional values to go?

Comment: @Eumel i want to ger rid of that dimension basically,its garbage values which i don't want to consider

Comment: thats not how this works...

Answer (score 2):

Method [`np.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) will only work if the axis you're looking to squeeze has a size of `1`, otherwise, it simply can't make the axis disappear without discarding part of the array's data...

In you're case, going from `(2, 6, 64, 64, 1)`, to `(6, 64, 64, 1)`, you would just select one of the two sub-arrays. Either with `out_hmaps[0]` (first one), or `out_hmaps[1]` (second one).

Comment: is there a way to get rid of both arrays..? @ivan

Comment: What do you mean by that?