# Creating training and testing data for neural network using multiple input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, root-framework

For the neural network I need to separate my data into testing and training which I do using train_test_split from sklearn.

Hopefully this makes it clear.

1.) I have multiple data files:df1, df2, df3, df4 ,df5, .... (root files)

2.) I want to combine these data files into one large data file

3.) I need to split the large data file into training and testing data

4.) I need to ensure that the training data is equally taken from each input data file. I do not want the training data to take 10% from df5, 20%, from d4, 30% from d3, 1% from d2 and 39% from d1. But I do want 20% of the training data take evenly from df1, df2, df3, df4 and df5.

5.) train_test_split from sklearn will not make this split evenly therefore I created a for loop as shown below which creates issues

6.) I need help coming up with another route to extract the training and testing data from the data files because my for loop is not working

What have I done so far

Step 1:
Created list for training and testing

```
Input_Train []
Input_Test = []

Output_Train = []
Output_Test = []
```

Step 2: (done on a for-loop for each file)
Open each individual file and does stuff to extract data

Step 3: (still in for-loop)
Using sklearn split the data into training and testing for each individual data file

```
InputFeature_train, InputFeature_test, OutputLabel_train, OutputLabel_test = train_test_split( input_features, output_Labels, train_size = 0.2)

Store the output into the list created in step 1 above 

Input_Train.append(InputFeature_train)
Input_Test.append(InputFeature_test)
Output_Train.append(OutputLabel_train)
Output_Test.append(OutputLabel_test)
```

At this point I have all of the data stored into list

Step 4: (Outside of for loop)
Convert the list into numpy arrays

```
Input_Train.np.asarray(Input_Train)
Input_Test.np.asarray(Input_Test)
Output_Train.np.asarray(Output_Train)
Output_Test.np.asarray(Output_Test)
```

Step 5:
When I print out the shape (Input_Train.shape)  I get

```
Input train shape (2,) --> Not what I need
```

Step 6: (Doing some googling )
I found that someone else had a similar issues
[ValueError: cannot select an axis to squeeze out which has size not equal to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68588996/valueerror-cannot-select-an-axis-to-squeeze-out-which-has-size-not-equal-to-one)

Since my dimension will be more than 1, I cannot squeeze (or reshape) this numpy array (which might have a dimension of  10+ )

But following the comments I did

```
Input_Train[0].shape --> I got the right values for just one data file
```

Step 7: My question
Does anyone have a solution on how to gather the training and testing data evenly from multiple samples? The current for loop that I have setup does not work.

Step 8: Thank you in advance for any help. If you can find a link that can help me please let me know and my apologies for not finding the link myself.

*********Update***********

```
#Names to get from root file
tagNames = ["m1_pt", "m2_pt", "m1_eta", "m2_eta", "m1_phi", "m2_phi"]  

#Array list
Input_Train []
Input_Test = []

Output_Train = []
Output_Test = []


data_file = ["data_file1.root", "data_file2.root"]
for df in range(len(data_file)):
        #Check to make sure file is available 
        if os.path.exists(data_file[df]):
                #Opening ROOT file 
                rfile = ROOT.TFile.Open(data_file[df])
                print("Successfully opened data file")
        else:
                #Failure to open file
                print("File not found, please try another file: ",data_file[df])

        #Get tree name from root file
        rootTreeName = "tag"

        intree = rfile.Get(rootTreeName)

        #Getting values that are does not have index =-1 (these are invalid data points)
        Ifp= tree2array(intree, branches = tagNames, selection = "index != -1")
        num_from_Ifp = Ifp.size #Size of the Ifp

        #Putting the Ifp values into a list
        input_features=[]
        for i in range(num_from_Ifp):
          input_features.append(list(Ifp[i]))

        #Converting list to an array
        input_features=np.array(input_features)

        #################################
        # Doing the same thing for the output labels
        #################################
        #output_values is a list with two values ( output_values = [0,1]). 0 corresponds to  muon in the first position and 1 corresponds to muon in the second position. There is no particular order at this point.
        Ofp = tree2array(intree, branches = ["output_values"], selection = "index != -1")
       # The line above (Ofp = ...) will tell use which muon is the correct one. It will give us the value 1 or 0
       # here is the output just to give you an idea
       # [(0,) (1,) (1,) ... (1,) (1,) (1,)]


    #Now we need to create a method to let the nn to know which muon is correct.
    #Creating an array that identifies the correct muon 
        # [ 0, 1 ] --> muon in the first position is correct
        # [ 1, 0 ] --> muon in the second position is correct

        output_Labels = np.eye(input_features.shape[0], 2)
        for i in range(input_features.shape[0]):
          output_Labels[i,0] = Ofp[i][0]
          output_Labels[i,1] = Ofp[i][0]


       #Using sklearn split the data into training and testing for each individual data file
       InputFeature_train, InputFeature_test, OutputLabel_train, OutputLabel_test = train_test_split( input_features, output_Labels, train_size = 0.2)

       Input_Train.append(InputFeature_train)
       Input_Test.append(InputFeature_test)
       Output_Train.append(OutputLabel_train)
       Output_Test.append(OutputLabel_test)



#converting list to numpy array
Input_Train = np.asarray(Input_Train)
Input_Test  = np.asarray(Input_Test )

Output_Train  = np.asarray(Output_Train)
Output_Test   = np.asarray(Output_Test )


#Printing the shape and type (note going to the first update will show you the values I get from this statement)
print("Input train shape"  , Input_Train.shape)
print("Input train type"  , type(Input_Train))
print("Input test shape"  , Input_Test.shape)
print("Output train shape"  , Output_Train.shape)
print("Ouput train type", type(Output_Train))
print("Output test shape"  , Output_Test.shape)

print("Input train [0] shape"  , Input_Train[0].shape)
print("Input train [0] type"  , type(Input_Train[0]))
print("Input test [0] shape"  , Input_Test[0].shape)
print("Output train [0] shape"  , Output_Train[0].shape)
print("Ouput train [0] type", type(Output_Train[0]))
print("Output test [0] shape"  , Output_Test[0].shape)


print("Input train [1] shape"  , Input_Train[1].shape)
print("Input train [1] type"  , type(Input_Train[1]))
print("Input test [1] shape"  , Input_Test[1].shape)
print("Output train [1] shape"  , Output_Train[1].shape)
print("Ouput train [1] type", type(Output_Train[1]))
print("Output test [1] shape"  , Output_Test[1].shape)
```

********Update*******
provide the outputs of some Ifp[i] rows as well
I have simplified the number of tagNames for this question. Here are all of the outputs

```
#Successfully opened data file --> Data File #1
Provide output as well - Ifp [(0.29471233, 0.14390038,  1.0457071 , -1.585283  ,  2.7644567,  0.3607209)
 (0.3863323 , 0.09461627,  2.1371427 ,  0.29747197,  2.7828562, -1.3958061)
 (0.30622792, 0.17158653, -1.428787  , -1.027902  ,  1.4112458, -1.6929731)
 ...
 (0.6137445 , 0.10678114, -0.6032986 , -0.4376499 , -3.0313694,  2.2488282)
 (0.39696205, 0.11587278, -0.48610905, -2.0285435 ,  1.487525 , -2.8935661)
 (0.43279374, 0.26002622,  1.6778533 ,  1.8011662 ,  1.2196023, -1.2002599)]
#Print out of Ofp [(0,) (1,) (1,) ... (1,) (1,) (1,)]

#Successfully opened data file --> Data file #2
Provide output as well - Ifp [(0.17516829, 0.15851186,  1.1060914 , -0.04039998,  1.2502128 ,  1.2712404)
 (0.42542648, 0.04648708, -0.23667681,  2.1146367 ,  0.15884383,  0.8808505)
 (0.32750598, 0.13000336, -0.78815895,  1.2549461 , -1.8893875 , -2.531463 )
 ...
 (0.38410604, 0.11572407, -0.24459349, -1.3212451 , -2.389494  , -1.6892412)
 (0.19714127, 0.10412598, -1.4186419 ,  1.8119588 , -0.47204217,  2.0771308)
 (0.3643554 , 0.11526036,  0.7342873 , -0.6727072 , -1.534371  ,  2.6366332)]
#Print out of Ofp [(1,) (1,) (1,) ... (1,) (0,) (1,)]

Input train shape (2,)
Input train  type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Input test  shape (2,)
Output train  shape (2,)
Ouput train  type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Output test  shape (2,)

Input train [0] shape (1423, 6)
Input train [0] type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Input test [0] shape (5692, 6)
Output train [0] shape (1423, 2)
Ouput train [0] type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Output test [0] shape (5692, 2)

Input train [1] shape (1408, 6)
Input train [1]  type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Input test [1]  shape (5634, 6)
Output train [1]  shape (1408, 2)
Ouput train [1]  type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Output test [1] shape (5634, 2)
```

****Update****
I do not get an error but a shape issue of Input_Train which is noted under Step 5 and shown under the second Update.

Issue -->Input train shape (2,) ( I do not want this)

Printing Input_Train[0].shape -->Input train [0] shape (1423, 6)

Printing Input_Train[1].shape   -->Input train [1] shape (1408, 6)

What I want is to add these to arrays (Input_Train[0] and Input_Train[1] so that my shape gives Input_Train.shape --> (2831, 6)

not Input_Train.shape (2,).

Comment: `I got the right values for just one data file` so you mean your dataframes do not have the same number of columns?

Comment: It works for one data file. But when you add an additional data file is when it breaks.

Comment: That's not my question...

Comment: Btw it is very helpful if you can provide your full code instead of pseudo code like in the current answer.

Comment: I have provided the full code. Also, what do you mean by the number of columns?

Comment: Note that the code works when data_file just has one sample but when I add two or more then it no longer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is posted below. The answer to my problem was  solved with help from @meyere_mit_ai and Minh-Long Luu, thank you!

A simplified version

```
#Define Arrays for Train and Test for both Input and Output arrays
nn_InputFeatures_Train     = []
nn_InputFeatures_Test      = []

nn_OutputputFeatures_Train = []
nn_OutputputFeatures_Test  = []

InputFeature_train, InputFeature_test, OutputLabel_train, OutputLabel_test = train_test_split( input_features, output_Labels, train_size = 0.2)
        for e in InputFeature_train:
                nn_InputFeatures_Train.append(list((e)))
        for f in InputFeature_test:
                nn_InputFeatures_Test.append(list((f)))
        for g in OutputLabel_train:
                nn_OutputputFeatures_Train.append(list((g)))
        for h in OutputLabel_test:
                nn_OutputputFeatures_Test.append(list((h)))

#Converting Testing, Validation and Training data into arrays
nn_InputFeatures_Train = np.asarray(nn_InputFeatures_Train )
nn_InputFeatures_Test  = np.asarray(nn_InputFeatures_Test  )

nn_OutputLabels_Train  = np.asarray(nn_OutputLabels_Train  )
nn_OutputLabels_Test   = np.asarray(nn_OutputLabels_Test   )

#Now the arrays are properly stacked how I want them. If anyone has a better solution, feel free to comment! :)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following route:

1. make sure your data frames have the same columns
2. load the dataframes into a list
3. initialize a new data frame with the same columns
4. iterate over the list with the data frames
5. for every data frame: filter out invalid data, get a sample using the df.sample() method and append this sample to the newly initialized dataframe
6. go on with this df

Comment: Very silly question but can you explain what columns mean? Are you referring to the output of the shape. Looking at the first update, which value in the shape would be my columns?

Comment: @LearnByDoing can you provide the outputs of some `Ifp[i]` rows as well?

Comment: yes, I have provided all of the outputs. Hopefully this helps

Comment: I really think, you have to get a basic understanding of pandas DataFrames and numpy Arrays, first.

Comment: BTW: What happens, when you are looping? Is an error raised? What kind of error?

Comment: @meyer_mit_ai I have addressed your question in the 3rd update. I hope this answers your question. I will look deeper into understanding DataFrame and NumPy Arrays. Hopefully I find a solution

Comment: @meyer_mit_ai I think I might see what you are stating in your answer. Since each data file will have a different shape (well the first value). I need to make them all equal by inserting dummy values so that I can concatenate them. But when I continue with the data array I need to make sure I flag the dummy values that I have included.

Comment: As far as I understand, you get an one-dimensional array where you want two dimensions. Look into numpy’s concatenate(), stack(), hstack(), vstack(), dstack() and reshape() methods.